# muliple model in one controler

Tags: codeigniter

how to load multiple model in codigniter

```
class c_home extends CI_Controller {

         function __construct(){
           parent::__construct();

           $this->load->model('muser/m_user');
           $this->load->model('mcommon/m_common');

         }
```

i have two model m_user and m_common. m_user load but m_common not loaded give Error Message: Undefined property:  c_user::$m_common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the model correctly extends the CI_Model for m_common

example:

```
 class m_common extends CI_Model{    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with multiple model in codigniter. There is a problem with your m_common model. Check it:

```
  function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();

      // $this->load->model('muser/m_user');
       $this->load->model('mcommon/m_common');

     }
```